# adding constraints in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ddl, check-constraints

A column should have its field as either 'cl', 'sl' or 'el'. How to add such constraints in oracel sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [CHECK constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
   id int NOT NULL,
   col varchar(10)
   CONSTRAINT chk_col CHECK (col IN ('cl', 'sl', 'el' ))
)
```

or use ALTER command like

```
alter table mytable 
       add col varchar(10) 
       constraint chk_col check(col IN ('cl', 'sl', 'el' ))
```

Comment: @gopal:- Use the alter table command which I have added in my answer,

Answer (score 0):

If the column is to contain 'cl', 'sl' or 'el' only, then these strings certainly have *meanings*. You can simply add a check constraint to your table, but that would leave the matter rather undocumented.

For this reason you may want to add a small lookup table instead:

```
leave  description
cl     Casual Leave
sl     Sick Leave 
el     Earned Leave
```

In your existing table you'd simply put a foreign key constraint to that lookup table then.